# Duplicating array items based on a value within the array itself

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to duplicate array items by multiplying them by the value of the quantity within their array. For example I currently have an array which has a quantity element like so:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 18551
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 10
            [category_id] => 52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 15283
            [quantity] => 2
            [text] => 7
            [category_id] => 52
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 17756
            [quantity] => 2
            [text] => 7
            [category_id] => 49
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 15026
            [quantity] => 1
            [text] => 3
            [category_id] => 49
        )
)
```

And what I am trying to achieve based on the above would output like the following:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 18551
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 10
                [category_id] => 52
            )
    
        [1] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 15283
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 7
                [category_id] => 52
            )
        
        [2] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 15283
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 7
                [category_id] => 52
            )
    
        [3] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 17756
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 7
                [category_id] => 49
            )
    
        [4] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 17756
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 7
                [category_id] => 49
            )
    
        [5] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 15026
                [quantity] => 1
                [text] => 3
                [category_id] => 49
            )
    )
```

My code looks like the below:

```
foreach ($plants_array as $pa) {
    foreach ($pa as $quantity) {
        $quantity_array = $pa['quantity'];
    }
    $new_array[] = $plants_array * $pa['quantity'];
}
```

however this produces the following error: Unsupported operand types

Reading about this indicates the error is because I am trying to muliply array items, but that is exactly what im trying to achieve.

Is anybody able to point me in the direction of how this can be achieved?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You have seriously confused the mathematical operation of multiplying with the operation of creating multiple copies of an array, that is the root of your confusion. You can't create copies with a mathematical operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that out of your code, it may not be the most effective but i think it works:

```
$new_array=[];
foreach ($plants_array as $pa) 
{
    for($i=0;$i<$pa['quantity'];$i++) 
    {
        $new_array[]=['product_id' =>$pa['product_id'],'quantity' => 1,'text' => $pa['text'],'category_id' => $pa['text']];
    }
}
```